# Objective-C alternative to C struct?

Tags: objective-c, struct, automatic-ref-counting

In the Mac Developer Library section "Transitioning to ARC Release Notes" it states "…rather than use a struct, you can create an Objective-C class to manage the data instead" but doesn't elaborate further.

Any suggestions on an Objective-C object that would be a reasonable alternative? I have the following C struct that I'm using for state values that I need to store when my app quits and restore when run again:

```
struct app_data
{
    bool enable_flag;
    bool random_flag;
    …
    int wait_slider_value;
};
```

Comment: A class? And instances of that class, perhaps? After all, that's why the language is called **Objective**-C...

Comment: Futhermore, the struct you listed is not one that needs to be remade, because it doesn't contain any pointers to Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 6.0, you can use the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods [`application:willEncodeRestorableStateWithCoder:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW38) and [`application:didDecodeRestorableStateWithCoder:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW39) to save and restore state. Keep in mind that these methods are not designed for saving actual persistent data to disk, the use of these methods should be for saving and restoring the UI state.